# Hoare logic: how does a strictly decreasing loop variant by itself prove termination?

Tags: language-agnostic, logic, verification, variant

Referring to the [while rule for total correctness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic#While_rule_for_total_correctness), WP seems to tell me that just finding a loop variant that strictly decreases is enough to prove termination.  I can't accept that, either because I'm missing something or the rule is wrong.  Consider

```
int i = 1000;
while(true) i--;
```

in which the value of variable `i` is a strictly decreasing loop variant, but the loop certainly doesn't terminate.

Surely the rule needs to have an additional precondition, something like *i<0 → ¬B* (where *B* is the loop condition in the axiom schema) so that the loop condition eventually 'catches' the loop variant and exits.

Or have I missed something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The loop-variant must be a natural number. A natural number cannot decrease past zero. Using big words, the loop variant is a value that is monotonically decreasing with respect to a well-founded relation. It's the well-foundedness that's missing from your reasoning.

Comment: Or putting it another way, `i` is not a strictly decreasing variant in any language I know - in most cases it reaches a minimum and then either wraps around (i.e. gets bigger) or else triggers undefined behavior (which might terminate the loop, you never know). Perhaps in some real cases, and hypothetically we can consider that `int` is a bignum in some language, in which case n.m.'s full explanation is required - it's decreasing but not with respect to a well-order.

Comment: @Steve It does not necessarily do either, see [bignum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bignum). If you have a Linux machine, type `bc` at the terminal. There, you have an infinite-precision programming language at your fingertips.

Comment: `bc` doesn't have a type called `int`, does it? So I didn't consider it as one of the real languages that the questioner's code snippet might be. Hence it's not in either of my first two cases. If it does then it's in my last case (and it fails the "must be a natural number" / "must be well-ordered" test). I don't know Mathematica, but maybe there you can have a strictly decreasing ordinal which is not necessarily a natural number, but is in a well-order and hence qualifies!

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the Wikipedia article:

> [...] the condition *B* must imply that *t* is
>   not a minimal element of its range,
>   for otherwise the premise of this rule
>   would be false.

In the case at hand, *B* is `true` and *t* is `i`.  `true` makes no implication about the minimality of `i`, so the premise of the rule is not met.

Comment: The text you quoted is implied by the variant being *strictly* decreasing from one iteration to the next, which it's not in OP's example. (Depending on the language, OP's example invokes UB or increases by 2^32-1 at some step.)

Answer (score 1):

The usual ordering "<" is well-founded on the natural numbers, but not on the integers.  In order for a relation to be well-founded, every non-empty subset of its domain must have a minimal element.  Since it can be shown that there is no infinite descending chain with respect to a well-founded relation, it follows that a loop with a variant must terminate.

Of course the condition of the loop must be false in the case of a minimal element!

A variant need not be restricted to the natural numbers, however.  Transfinite ordinals are also well-ordered.